# Keras parameter search and log loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

I'm building a Keras simple classifier model for a multiclass problem where classes are not exclusive. In addition, I would like to add sklearn exhaustive parameter search with cross-validation. This is the trivial model:

```python
def build_model(embedding_size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(10000, embedding_size, input_length=100))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation="sigmoid"))
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

batch_size = 64
epochs = 2
```

Here's my first solution with manual cross-validation (without parameter search).

```python
embedding_size=32

skf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)
valid_evals = []
for train_indices in skf.split(train_full_x):
    kfold_train_x = train_full_x[train_indices[0]]
    kfold_valid_x = train_full_x[train_indices[1]]
    kfold_train_y = train_full_y[train_indices[0]]
    kfold_valid_y = train_full_y[train_indices[1]]
    model = build_model(embedding_size)
    model.fit(kfold_train_x, kfold_train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
    valid_evals.append(model.evaluate(kfold_valid_x, kfold_valid_y))

valid_evals = np.array(valid_evals)
print(valid_evals)
print("LogLoss: %.4f +/- %.4f" % (valid_evals.mean(axis=0)[0], valid_evals.std(axis=0)[0]))
print("Accuracy: %.2f%% +/- %.2f%%" % (valid_evals.mean(axis=0)[1] * 100, valid_evals.std(axis=0)[1] * 100))
```

The results are quite consistent:

```
[[0.05730336 0.98051361]
 [0.0606665  0.98065738]
 [0.05717109 0.9801999 ]]
LogLoss: 0.0584 +/- 0.0016
Accuracy: 98.05% +/- 0.02%
```

This code works fine, returns a validation accuracy of ~98% and a log loss of about `0.06`. I then tried adding `GridSearchCV` instead of rolling my own solution for parameter search (in the sample below the search space is trivially reduced to one choice only).

```
embedding_size = [32]
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)
param_grid = dict(embedding_size=embedding_size)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, param_grid=param_grid, return_train_score=True, cv=kfold)
results = grid.fit(train_x, train_y)
print("Best: %f using %s" % (results.best_score_, results.best_params_))
print(results.cv_results_)
```

This returns

```
Best: 0.980600 using {'embedding_size': 32}
0.980600 (0.000187) with: {'embedding_size': 32}
{'split2_train_score': array([0.9882294]), 'mean_train_score': array([0.98768258]), 'split0_train_score': array([0.98707933]), 'split1_train_score': array([0.98773903]), 'std_train_score': array([0.00047121]), 'mean_fit_time': array([8.7320834]), 'split1_test_score': array([0.98079212]), 'split0_test_score': array([0.98066088]), 'std_fit_time': array([0.19671295]), 'rank_test_score': array([1], dtype=int32), 'std_test_score': array([0.00018667]), 'param_embedding_size': masked_array(data=[32], mask=[False], fill_value='?', dtype=object), 'std_score_time': array([0.00984431]), 'split2_test_score': array([0.98034717]), 'mean_score_time': array([0.58589784]), 'params': [{'embedding_size': 32}], 'mean_test_score': array([0.98060006])}
```

Here I get an accuracy compatible with Keras manually splitting the training/validation. However, in my problem the relevant scoring function is the log loss, so I tried adding a `scoring="neg_log_loss"` as a parameter to `GridSearchCV`. **But in this case I get a score like `-0.29`.**

```
Best: -0.292518 using {'embedding_size': 32}
-0.292518 (0.002988) with: {'embedding_size': 32}
{'split1_train_score': array([-0.27363595]), 'std_score_time': array([0.01245312]), 'rank_test_score': array([1], dtype=int32), 'mean_test_score': array([-0.29251778]), 'std_fit_time': array([0.17412529]), 'split0_train_score': array([-0.27816725]), 'split1_test_score': array([-0.28917072]), 'mean_score_time': array([0.40924891]), 'params': [{'embedding_size': 32}], 'split0_test_score': array([-0.29195843]), 'split2_test_score': array([-0.2964242]), 'split2_train_score': array([-0.26628012]), 'mean_fit_time': array([8.75646718]), 'mean_train_score': array([-0.27269444]), 'std_test_score': array([0.00298751]), 'std_train_score': array([0.00489836]), 'param_embedding_size': masked_array(data=[32], mask=[False], fill_value='?', dtype=object)}
```

I expected a difference in sign (due to how `neg_log_loss` works) but not in value.

What am I doing wrong? Or... is there another way to get `GridSearchCV` working with cross-validation and log loss?

Thank you

N.B. I did not set a random seed, but instead run both examples many times, so that randomness should not be the cause of the difference shown.

Comment: The fact that you are getting negative loss makes me think that GridSearchCV is seeing train_y as categorial numbers rather than sparse/one hot...

Comment: A negative log loss using `neg_log_loss` seems [to be expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47754600/1169814). The train_y is in the form of `[[0, 0, 1, ...., 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, ...., 0, 1], ...]`

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'binary multiclass' problem: 'binary' refers to the number of classes, not to the way they are encoded; yours is a multi-class multi-label one

Comment: Are you sure the 0.05 value returned by Keras refers to the *validation* (and not training) error? You don't show this part in your code (and we don't ask for a [minimum verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for nothing).

Comment: Hello @desertnaut, I expanded my answer with code for both cases and corrected the problem classification.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you have omitted the predict step. Logloss only requires y_test and y_predict and in order to get y_predict you need to invoke the predict method. So, here is what works for me when I use GridSearchCV with a knn classifier. GridSearchCV is instantiated as cv.

```
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = cv.predict(X_test)   # grid.predict(X_test) in your case

from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
print('Log_loss: {}'.format(log_loss(y_test, y_predict)))
```

Addition:

I have been playing with a fairly inaccurate knn/GridSearchCV classifier and have realised a couple of things which may be relevant as well:

1. If I run the cv without and with scoring='neg_log_loss' and calculate indepently the log_loss as I have suggested above, the result from the latter is different - 6.536 vs 6.716, respectively. So, it is higher when the optimisation is based on optimising the log_loss rather than on optimising the accuracy. Clearly, the vector of labels is slightly different for each optimisation condition. This is probably not suprising, and as you have noted the difference is not that big anyway.
2. Since you are using return_train_score=True and the results from all cv steps are stored in .cv_results_ it is easy to visualise train and test scores. Clearly, scoring replaces the accuracy with the log loss in the mean_test and mean_train score columns as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm using GridSearchCV to make a parameter search on different variations of my model. After the `fit` method I expected an array of scores related to the loss, so I can check whether some options are promising or not. Using `predict` gives me no idea of how different parameters behave because it is already using the best estimator, refit on the `fit` scores previously computed.

Comment: Then you need to somehow invoke predict every time a parameter changes. I have not done this and can't offer an off-the-shelf solution. There may be a way to do it using nested pipelines. The less elegant but certain way to achieve this is to iterate through a dictionary and pass to GridSearchCV or perhaps just the kerasClassifier a more limited slice of your parameters, predict after each fit and add the logloss to the dictionary.

Comment: I'm puzzled... if this is the right way what's the point of using GridSearchCV at all instead of using of a manual cross_validation + parameter search...?

Comment: Reading your question again, I realized it has two parts. First, the difference in log-loss values despite the similar accuracy. Log-loss penalizes more labels that are confident and wrong, so it seems plausible to have different values for the log-loss despite the similar accuracy. The second part is to find the log-loss for every grid-search point. After you have called grid.predict(), can you identify the log-loss in the columns of pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)?

Comment: I simplified the question, trivially reducing the param search to one point, so that you can probably ignore the second part of your analysis. You can find in the updated answer the result of both examples. Thanks in the meantime.