# Why do `scoring="neg_log_loss"` and `scoring=make_scorer(log_loss)` give such different validation scores?

Tags: scikit-learn

[Sklearn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) seems to imply that the `neg_log_loss` scoring uses log_loss as the scorer.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081251/sklearn-metrics-log-loss-is-positive-vs-scoring-neg-log-loss-is-negative) question tries to clarify what is happening under the hood and the accepted answer says neg_log_loss is simply equal to - log_loss.  However, the attached example shows that this is not the case.

What is the relationship between `scoring = "neg_log_loss"` and `scoring=make_scorer(log_loss)`? The apparent discontinuities make me think that `neg_log_loss` is using probabilities rather than predictions in the loss. How can I alter my code below so that each method returns the same results?

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, log_loss, make_scorer, get_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

X,y = make_classification(random_state = 0)

cv = KFold(10)


nll = lambda y, ypred: -1*log_loss(y, ypred)


param_grid = {'C':1/np.logspace(-5,2, base = np.exp(1))}
model = LogisticRegression(penalty = 'l1', solver = 'liblinear', max_iter=10_000)

gscv_scoring = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv = cv, scoring = 'neg_log_loss').fit(X,y)    
gscv_make_scoring = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv = cv, scoring = make_scorer(nll)).fit(X,y)    


fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi = 120)

r1 = pd.DataFrame(gscv_scoring.cv_results_)
r2 = pd.DataFrame(gscv_make_scoring.cv_results_)


plt.plot(r1.param_C, r1.mean_test_score)
plt.plot(r2.param_C, r2.mean_test_score)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, scoring='neg_log_loss', cv=2)
```

You will get back the negative probability. If you passed in the metrics.log_loss directly via `make_scorer`, you will need to set `greater_is_better=False, needs_proba=True`

To get the equivalent by using metrics.log_loss directly, you need to pass it the outcome of `predict_proba` from the model, not the predicted labels.

```
y_probs = model.predict_proba(X_train)
log_loss(y_train, y_probs)
```

This will give you back the positive probability. Then, as you mentioned, they only differ by a sign.

Comment: You can't have negative probability, not in any normal universe anyway :) But you can have a negative *log* probability....